# How to invoke a script which creates django app and project from views.py

Tags: python, django

I am fresher.On click of a button, I want a project and an app to be created automatically in C: . So, I have written a python script like-
//myscript.py

```
import os

os.chdir('c:\\')
os.system('django-admin startproject myproject')    
os.system('django-admin startapp myapp')
```

in views.py, I have invoked this python script

//views.py

```
def functionname(request)    
     os.system('python myscript.py)
```

i have written ajax for the button click also. But it is not working.So please me as to how to invoke a script from views which creates an  django app and django project in specified path

Comment: Why don't you make your script to be just a function and call it? Is it used anywhere else?

Comment: But apart from that, what do you mean `it is not working`? You need to tell us more details about what error do you have and stuff like that.

Comment: when i execute the python script- myscript.py in command prompt, it works and a project and app is created.so the script has no problem. but it is not working when invoked from views.

Comment: Can you please brief out regarding script to be just a function.I'm new to python:(

Comment: There is no error reported. But the app isn't getting created in the specified folder

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's your intention to make only 3 lines of code to be in a script unless you run the script somewhere else, but I think you could just move them inside your views.py. You can always make several lines of code to be a function:

In views.py

```
import os

def create_project:
    os.chdir('c:\\')
    os.system('django-admin startproject myproject')    
    os.system('django-admin startapp myapp')

def function(request):
    create_project()
```

If you really want to keep that part in a separate file, you could do:

In your myscript.py:

```
import os

def create_project:
    os.chdir('c:\\')
    os.system('django-admin startproject myproject')    
    os.system('django-admin startapp myapp')
# this would run the function when you run the script alone
if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_project()
```

In you views.py:

```
import myscript

def function(request):
    myscript.create_project()
```

It's a better idea to handle python using python instead of using operating system, because os environment might change and might swallow errors that otherwise easy to figure out in python.

Comment: ImportError: Could not import settings 'project.settings'.Is it on sys.path. No module named project.settings

Comment: ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sy
s.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named myproject.settings

Comment: Does that happen before? Did you add your `myproject` in you python path?

Comment: yes I have added myproject in my python path. I have checked sys.path and have placed myproject in python path only. But it gives an error as myproject.settings not found. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you have environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` defined?

Comment: yes,DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is defined and it equals myproject.settings. I even checked the wsgi file, but the error says no module defined myproject.settings, Import error

Comment: Well,it worked on my PC,app and project got successfully created. But the error is again repeated on the server and other systems.Unable to figure out the problem.Please help.Finally I want a project and an app to be created by running django commands in views.py.

Comment: Well, I'm helpless here because I don't have access to your PC and your prod environment so I couldn't tell what's missing and what's wrong.